# Celery: how to organize complex dataflow between tasks?

Tags: canvas, celery

Is there any way to control arguments passed to next task in chain in celery? For example, I have a two tasks which both have presence in final results and second one uses part of first task result data to do its job. Some sample illustration code below:

```py
import celery
import random

worker = celery.Celery()

@worker.task
def first():
    return(
        random.randint(1,9), # argument for second call
        # just a bunch of data I want to see in results
        # but not needed for second call
        [random.randint(1,9) for _ in xrange(100)]
    )

@worker.task
def second(number):
    return [random.randint(1,9) for _ in xrange(number)]
```

Second call depends on first so it must be a chain. But I want final results include first's data too without bypassing it through second task. So simplest way to do that is:

```py
argument, partial1 = first.s().apply_async().get()
partial2 = second.s(argument).apply_async().get()
results = (partial1, partial2)
```

But documentation [says](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-synchronous-subtasks) it is wrong way. How to do it right?

Comment: Rather curious as to what you're trying to accomplish I believe you may be trying to approach this from the wrong angle.

Comment: I agree my synthetic example is too simplicated. I'm trying to avoid piping bunch of unused data through whole chain and yield it to some kind of accumulator at any step maybe. Or find some kind of another cleaner solution.

Comment: Have you considered storing the data in some backend service like redis?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
(partial1, partial2) = (first.s() | second.s(return_value_from_first))().get()
```

Just pipe the input of first task to second task.

```
import celery
import random

worker = celery.Celery()

@worker.task
def first():
    return(random.randint(1,9), [random.randint(1,9) for _ in xrange(100)])

@worker.task
def second(return_value_from_first):
    number, partial1 = return_value_from_first
    return [partial1, random.randint(1,9) for _ in xrange(number)]
```

Comment: I thought about this. This is a bad idea in my case. first and second in real approach are groups of another tasks. So many overhead to pipe unused data through a bunch of tasks.

Comment: Also it wont work (will but ugly) for longer chains.